# 64bit Qt build on WIndows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2013, qt5

I’m trying to build 64bit Qt 5.2.0 from source with Visual Studio 2013. I configure the build with the following options:

```
configure.bat -c++11 -no-angle -opengl desktop -nomake examples -opensource -nomake tests -confirm-license
```

Then I simply run nmake.
Unfortunately, the build stops almost immediately with the following error:

```
SOME_PATH\5.2.0-src\qtbase\src\corelib\codecs\qutfcodec.cpp : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file: '.obj\release\qutfcodec.obj': No such file or directory
```

32bit builds work ok. Did anyone encounter such behavior?

Comment: Seems bug in project/build files, that `.obj/` seems suspcicious, maybe it should be `./obj/`. Another thing it could be is, you have too long paths, try building it so that `SOME_PATH` is `C:\qt` or something short like that.

Comment: The path is quite short and 32bit build with the same configuration works.

Comment: For Visual Studio, you cannot enable/disable c++11 support.  The "-c++11" is ignored in the configure step.  Also, if you are building from git and compiled for 32bit first, try calling "git clean -dfx" first to remove any temporary build files.